React and Tailwind CSS styling for making a special card component
This is what I want to make using React, it is a project component:

I have tried various ways to do it but cannot seem to find the correct documentation for help. I am also struggling to use next/image, to make sure it is correct size.
This is what I got so far.
const Project = ({ image, titile, description, technologies }) => {
  return (
    <div className="relative w-full h-64 bg-white">
      <Image fill src={"/placeholder.jpg"} />
      <div className="absolute w-[50%] h-8 bg-green-500 top-10 -left-10">
        Express, MongoDB, Node.js, React.js
      </div>
      <p>Project #2</p>
      <p>Blah blah blahs</p>
    </div>
  );
};

And it looks like this:


You want the inner div overflow 10px to the left of the wrapper div.
this should work:
export function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: '200px',width:"400px", backgroundColor: 'lightgray', padding: '10px', position: 'relative' }}>
      <div style={{ height: '10px', backgroundColor: 'blue', position: 'absolute', left: '-10px', width: 'calc(100% + 10px)' }}></div>
    </div>

  );
}

you can test in this react playground

The left property of the inner div is set to -10px, causing it to start 10 pixels to the left of the left edge of the wrapper div.

The width property is set to calc(100% + 10px) to ensure the inner div spans the full width of the wrapper div plus an additional 10 pixels to the left.


